java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.fleatiger.MainApplication package com.fleatiger
`
package.json

{
  "name": "fleatiger",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.3.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.2.1",
    "@react-native/codegen": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.10.1",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@rneui/themed": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "glob": "^11.0.0",
    "haversine": "^1.1.1",
    "lru-cache": "^11.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.45",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.74.3",
    "react-native-animated-spinkit": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1306.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.4",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.17.1",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.4.19",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-grid-component": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.15.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.17.3",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-otp-textinput": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.32.0",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-stopwatch-timer": "^0.0.21",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "rn-wave-bottom-bar": "^2.2.36"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.8",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.74.85",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}


android/app/src/main/java/com/fleatiger/MainApplication.kt
android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.fleatiger, PID: 8736 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.fleatiger.MainApplication package com.fleatiger: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fleatiger.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~TY6QgGHMsvP9Z-C-9zy6mQ==/com.fleatiger-T9sa_zp1zzlHYDp9SkijNw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~TY6QgGHMsvP9Z-C-9zy6mQ==/com.fleatiger-T9sa_zp1zzlHYDp9SkijNw==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~TY6QgGHMsvP9Z-C-9zy6mQ==/com.fleatiger-T9sa_zp1zzlHYDp9SkijNw==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]] at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466) at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959) at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fleatiger.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~TY6QgGHMsvP9Z-C-9zy6mQ==/com.fleatiger-T9sa_zp1zzlHYDp9SkijNw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~TY6QgGHMsvP9Z-C-9zy6mQ==/com.fleatiger-T9sa_zp1zzlHYDp9SkijNw==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~TY6QgGHMsvP9Z-C-9zy6mQ==/com.fleatiger-T9sa_zp1zzlHYDp9SkijNw==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76) at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52) at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1282) at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458) at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
`
We've upgraded our API level from Android 33 to 34. Using the React Native helper, we resolved all dependency issues. However, after building the APK, we continue to encounter the same error. Despite trying numerous solutions, the issue persists. Could you assist us in resolving this?
**We are using the below versions on our react native app
**
Node: 20.16.0
NPM: 10.8.1
Java: Open JDK 21.0.4
Ruby: 3.2.1
Gradlew: 8.6
Kotlin: 1.9.22
React Native: 0.74.3
Android Studio: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
